# Some elements floating down on adding featured tag - CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-selectors

Following is my code which is working fine, but ones I am adding "featured" tag (class `.note`) to the list the last element (`4n`) is floating down, though in 3rd list item its displaying correctly. Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Code -

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.container { display: flex; background: #EEEEEE; padding: 10px; }
.list { display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 100%; }
.list-item { background: #FFFFFF; margin-bottom: 10px; width: 100%; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; padding: 20px; position: relative; }
.box { width: 25%; }
.box:nth-child(4n+5) { padding-top: 5px; }
.box:nth-child(4n+6) { padding-top: 5px; }
.box:nth-child(4n+7) { padding-top: 5px; }
.box:nth-child(4n+8) { padding-top: 5px; }
.header {font-weight: bold; }
.note { position: absolute; top: 0; background: red; color: #FFFFFF;  padding: 2px 10px; left: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="list">
    <div class="list-item">
      <div class="note">Featured</div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 1</div>
        <div class="content">Content 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 2</div>
        <div class="content">Content 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 3</div>
        <div class="content">Content 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 4</div>
        <div class="content">Content 4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 1</div>
        <div class="content">Content 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 2</div>
        <div class="content">Content 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 3</div>
        <div class="content">Content 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 4</div>
        <div class="content">Content 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 5</div>
        <div class="content">Content 5</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="note">Featured</div>
        <div class="header">Header 1</div>
        <div class="content">Content 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 2</div>
        <div class="content">Content 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 3</div>
        <div class="content">Content 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 4</div>
        <div class="content">Content 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 5</div>
        <div class="content">Content 5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 6</div>
        <div class="content">Content 6</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 1</div>
        <div class="content">Content 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 2</div>
        <div class="content">Content 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 3</div>
        <div class="content">Content 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 4</div>
        <div class="content">Content 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 5</div>
        <div class="content">Content 5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 6</div>
        <div class="content">Content 6</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 7</div>
        <div class="content">Content 7</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 1</div>
        <div class="content">Content 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 2</div>
        <div class="content">Content 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 3</div>
        <div class="content">Content 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 4</div>
        <div class="content">Content 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 5</div>
        <div class="content">Content 5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 6</div>
        <div class="content">Content 6</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 7</div>
        <div class="content">Content 7</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 8</div>
        <div class="content">Content 8</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
      <div class="note">Featured</div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 1</div>
        <div class="content">Content 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 2</div>
        <div class="content">Content 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 3</div>
        <div class="content">Content 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 4</div>
        <div class="content">Content 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 5</div>
        <div class="content">Content 5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 6</div>
        <div class="content">Content 6</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 7</div>
        <div class="content">Content 7</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 8</div>
        <div class="content">Content 8</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 9</div>
        <div class="content">Content 9</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Screenshot of error -

[image]

Comment: whats the isssue here?

Comment: Can you please add screenshot of your issue? Its hard to figure out.

Comment: @sunjeep : Check, I added screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nth-of-type` then make the featured a span element. Doing this it will work with or without the featured element:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.container { display: flex; background: #EEEEEE; padding: 10px; }
.list { display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 100%; }
.list-item { background: #FFFFFF; margin-bottom: 10px; width: 100%; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; padding: 20px; position: relative; }
.box { width: 25%; }
.box:nth-of-type(4n+5) { padding-top: 5px; }
.box:nth-of-type(4n+6) { padding-top: 5px; }
.box:nth-of-type(4n+7) { padding-top: 5px; }
.box:nth-of-type(4n+8) { padding-top: 5px; }
.header {font-weight: bold; }
.note { position: absolute; top: 0; background: red; color: #FFFFFF;  padding: 2px 10px; left: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="list">
    <div class="list-item">
      <span class="note">Featured</span>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 1</div>
        <div class="content">Content 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 2</div>
        <div class="content">Content 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 3</div>
        <div class="content">Content 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 4</div>
        <div class="content">Content 4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 1</div>
        <div class="content">Content 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 2</div>
        <div class="content">Content 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 3</div>
        <div class="content">Content 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 4</div>
        <div class="content">Content 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 5</div>
        <div class="content">Content 5</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="note">Featured</div>
        <div class="header">Header 1</div>
        <div class="content">Content 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 2</div>
        <div class="content">Content 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 3</div>
        <div class="content">Content 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 4</div>
        <div class="content">Content 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 5</div>
        <div class="content">Content 5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 6</div>
        <div class="content">Content 6</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 1</div>
        <div class="content">Content 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 2</div>
        <div class="content">Content 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 3</div>
        <div class="content">Content 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 4</div>
        <div class="content">Content 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 5</div>
        <div class="content">Content 5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 6</div>
        <div class="content">Content 6</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 7</div>
        <div class="content">Content 7</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 1</div>
        <div class="content">Content 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 2</div>
        <div class="content">Content 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 3</div>
        <div class="content">Content 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 4</div>
        <div class="content">Content 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 5</div>
        <div class="content">Content 5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 6</div>
        <div class="content">Content 6</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 7</div>
        <div class="content">Content 7</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 8</div>
        <div class="content">Content 8</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
      <div class="note">Featured</div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 1</div>
        <div class="content">Content 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 2</div>
        <div class="content">Content 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 3</div>
        <div class="content">Content 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 4</div>
        <div class="content">Content 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 5</div>
        <div class="content">Content 5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 6</div>
        <div class="content">Content 6</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 7</div>
        <div class="content">Content 7</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 8</div>
        <div class="content">Content 8</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 9</div>
        <div class="content">Content 9</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another idea is to add the featured using a pseudo element:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.container { display: flex; background: #EEEEEE; padding: 10px; }
.list { display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 100%; }
.list-item { background: #FFFFFF; margin-bottom: 10px; width: 100%; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; padding: 20px; position: relative; }
.box { width: 25%; }
.box:nth-child(4n+5) { padding-top: 5px; }
.box:nth-child(4n+6) { padding-top: 5px; }
.box:nth-child(4n+7) { padding-top: 5px; }
.box:nth-child(4n+8) { padding-top: 5px; }
.header {font-weight: bold; }
.note::before {content:"Featured"; position: absolute; top: 0; background: red; color: #FFFFFF;  padding: 2px 10px; left: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="list">
    <div class="list-item note">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 1</div>
        <div class="content">Content 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 2</div>
        <div class="content">Content 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 3</div>
        <div class="content">Content 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 4</div>
        <div class="content">Content 4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 1</div>
        <div class="content">Content 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 2</div>
        <div class="content">Content 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 3</div>
        <div class="content">Content 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 4</div>
        <div class="content">Content 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 5</div>
        <div class="content">Content 5</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item note">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 1</div>
        <div class="content">Content 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 2</div>
        <div class="content">Content 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 3</div>
        <div class="content">Content 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 4</div>
        <div class="content">Content 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 5</div>
        <div class="content">Content 5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 6</div>
        <div class="content">Content 6</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 1</div>
        <div class="content">Content 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 2</div>
        <div class="content">Content 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 3</div>
        <div class="content">Content 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 4</div>
        <div class="content">Content 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 5</div>
        <div class="content">Content 5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 6</div>
        <div class="content">Content 6</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 7</div>
        <div class="content">Content 7</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 1</div>
        <div class="content">Content 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 2</div>
        <div class="content">Content 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 3</div>
        <div class="content">Content 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 4</div>
        <div class="content">Content 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 5</div>
        <div class="content">Content 5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 6</div>
        <div class="content">Content 6</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 7</div>
        <div class="content">Content 7</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 8</div>
        <div class="content">Content 8</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 1</div>
        <div class="content">Content 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 2</div>
        <div class="content">Content 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 3</div>
        <div class="content">Content 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 4</div>
        <div class="content">Content 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 5</div>
        <div class="content">Content 5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 6</div>
        <div class="content">Content 6</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 7</div>
        <div class="content">Content 7</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 8</div>
        <div class="content">Content 8</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 9</div>
        <div class="content">Content 9</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the third `list-item` the `.note` DIV is a *child* of the first `.box` DIV, in the other `.box` DIVs the `.note` DIV is a *sibling* of the `.box` DIVs. Change that for all to be the same as in the third one.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  background: #EEEEEE;
  padding: 10px;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.list-item {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.box {
  width: 25%;
}

.box:nth-child(4n+5) {
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.box:nth-child(4n+6) {
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.box:nth-child(4n+7) {
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.box:nth-child(4n+8) {
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.header {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.note {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: red;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="list">
    <div class="list-item">

      <div class="box">
        <div class="note">Featured</div>
        <div class="header">Header 1</div>
        <div class="content">Content 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 2</div>
        <div class="content">Content 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 3</div>
        <div class="content">Content 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 4</div>
        <div class="content">Content 4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 1</div>
        <div class="content">Content 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 2</div>
        <div class="content">Content 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 3</div>
        <div class="content">Content 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 4</div>
        <div class="content">Content 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 5</div>
        <div class="content">Content 5</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="note">Featured</div>
        <div class="header">Header 1</div>
        <div class="content">Content 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 2</div>
        <div class="content">Content 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 3</div>
        <div class="content">Content 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 4</div>
        <div class="content">Content 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 5</div>
        <div class="content">Content 5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 6</div>
        <div class="content">Content 6</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 1</div>
        <div class="content">Content 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 2</div>
        <div class="content">Content 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 3</div>
        <div class="content">Content 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 4</div>
        <div class="content">Content 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 5</div>
        <div class="content">Content 5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 6</div>
        <div class="content">Content 6</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 7</div>
        <div class="content">Content 7</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 1</div>
        <div class="content">Content 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 2</div>
        <div class="content">Content 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 3</div>
        <div class="content">Content 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 4</div>
        <div class="content">Content 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 5</div>
        <div class="content">Content 5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 6</div>
        <div class="content">Content 6</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 7</div>
        <div class="content">Content 7</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 8</div>
        <div class="content">Content 8</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="note">Featured</div>
        <div class="header">Header 1</div>
        <div class="content">Content 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 2</div>
        <div class="content">Content 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 3</div>
        <div class="content">Content 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 4</div>
        <div class="content">Content 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 5</div>
        <div class="content">Content 5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 6</div>
        <div class="content">Content 6</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 7</div>
        <div class="content">Content 7</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 8</div>
        <div class="content">Content 8</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 9</div>
        <div class="content">Content 9</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Strange ..I thought 1st and 6th is more semantically correct..what is your opinion ?

Comment: yes, semantically they are, but then you would have to find another CSS selector (using additional classes, probably)